# Android/iOS app product description photos

Tags: ps

What tools/application/webs do they use to make nice description photos?

e.g https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instamag.activity

The demo pictures are very nice, any PS templates I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want screenshots of your phone running your iOS app, I used this with excellent success:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/screenshot-maker-pro/id673545271?mt=8

For android, you could just use this:
http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/device-art.html

Comment: Check my edit - you could use the android promotion tools provided by Google.